# Tournament dropout probability

Tags: tournament

Is there any concrete data about the probability than a random person will not end a tournament? (Obviously, the data can be further tallied with regard to age, Elo, rounds, prizes :-) and whatnot...)

(The forfeit probability is surely easier to compute via a megabase, you can add this data too.)

Comment: but the megabase only has a subset of real games?

Comment: @cmgchess: Frankly, I don't know... (From the documentary standpoint, it would make sense to keep such games, it's not that they take much space :-)

Comment: If they're a low-tier professional and are out of chances to get a prize in the last round, it's 100%